# Oracle SQL*Plus error with blanklines and multiple lines comments

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I'm trying to execute a query with SQL*Plus (command line) that is a VIEW.  SQL*Plus isn't supporting new lines or multiline comments ( /* -- */ ).

When I run `set sqlblanklines on`, it returns an error:

```
SQL> set sqlblanklines on
unknown SET option beginning "sqlblankli...".
```

So I ran 'help set' and it says that the command sqlblanklines (with an asterisk) is not supported by isql , but I'm using SQL*Plus indeed.

I don't know how to get rid of it, I've been frying my brain off about a couple days...

thanks in adv!!!

---

More details

The version is 8.0.6.0.0.

I'm running a script from a file. It shows many errors like this:

```
SQL> start /tmp/sql/pti/APPS.DIBVWIP001.sql
```

The errors are like

```
   unknown command beginning "and msi.i..." - rest of line ignored. 
   unknown command beginning "and msi.o..." - rest of line ignored. 
   unknown command beginning "and bic.c..." - rest of line ignored. 
   unknown command beginning "and bbm.b..." - rest of line ignored. 
   For a list of known commands enter HELP and to leave enter EXIT.
```

Before that block there's an blank line.. that's the point. I can't remove the blank lines from the scripts.

Comment: what error do you get when you try to run the query?

Comment: What version of SQL*Plus are you running? Are you typing the query directly into SQL*Plus or calling a script?

Comment: You know you are not allowed to use inline comments ? see: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch5.htm

Comment: Well, the version is 8.0.6.0.0. I'm running a script from a file. It shows many errors like this "SQL> start /tmp/sql/pti/APPS.DIBVWIP001.sql
unknown command beginning "and  msi.i..." - rest of line ignored.
unknown command beginning "and  msi.o..." - rest of line ignored.
unknown command beginning "and  bic.c..." - rest of line ignored.
unknown command beginning "and  bbm.b..." - rest of line ignored.
For a list of known commands enter HELP
and to leave enter EXIT.
" - Before that block there's an blank line.. that's the point. I can't remove the blank lines from the scripts.. =S

Comment: This article, Kevin, tells that I CAN comment a single inline ou multiple lines ...

Comment: You really should have your SQL*Plus version updated. If you are working on a 10g database you should have the Oracle 10g client tools installed and this would probably get round your problem. Is there a specific reason why you are having to use such an old (and desupported, i think) version of SQL*Plus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are working with an *ancient* version of the software.  So it's no good looking at a modern version of the manual.  If you consult [the SQL*Plus User's Guide for Oracle 8.0.5](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/A64702_01/doc/index.htm) you will discover that SET doesn't support SQLBLANKLINES, which is what the error message told you.

I'm not sure why the multi-line comments are giving you grief: according to the documentation that should be supported.  However, SQL*Plus - especially older versions - is sensitive to where we place the comments.  It doesn't like comments which are placed too early in the DDL command.  So if you're doing something like this ...

```
create  
/*  this is a comment
    which spans several lines
    oh yes
*/
or replace view my_view as select * from dual
/
```

... you might get some problems (although it runs fine in 11g).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Look at header of the result of an forms compilation: Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
     With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
PL/SQL Version 8.0.6.3.0 (Production) - Oracle is 10g but version of SQL*Plus seems to be 8. That is right ?

Comment: @Marcio - The database is a server application whereas SQL*Plus is a client application. So it is perfectly possible for them to be out-of-sync; in fact it's almost inevitable in large organizations :(  The database is certified to have backwards compatibility with older versions of SQL*Plus. (The reverse is not true, advanced versions of the client may not play nice with older versions of the database.)